# Expandable List View not in right order

Tags: android, expandablelistview

my expandable list view doesn't seem to be in right order.

Here is my dataprovider for it:

```
public class DataProvider {

public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo() {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> WorkoutDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> Workout_29 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Workout_29.add("Week One");
    Workout_29.add("Week Two");
    Workout_29.add("Week Three");
    Workout_29.add("Week Four");

    List<String> Workout_30 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Workout_30.add("Week One");
    Workout_30.add("Week Two");
    Workout_30.add("Week Three");
    Workout_30.add("Week Four");

    List<String> Workout_31 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Workout_31.add("Week One");
    Workout_31.add("Week Two");
    Workout_31.add("Week Three");
    Workout_31.add("Week Four");

    List<String> Workout_32 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Workout_32.add("Week One");
    Workout_32.add("Week Two");
    Workout_32.add("Week Three");
    Workout_32.add("Week Four");

    List<String> Workout_37 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Workout_37.add("Week One");
    Workout_37.add("Week Two");
    Workout_37.add("Week Three");
    Workout_37.add("Week Four");

    WorkoutDetails.put("Workout 29", Workout_29);
    WorkoutDetails.put("Workout 30", Workout_30);
    WorkoutDetails.put("Workout 31", Workout_31);
    WorkoutDetails.put("Workout 32", Workout_32);
    WorkoutDetails.put("Workout 37", Workout_37);

    return WorkoutDetails;
}

}
```

Here is where it is created:

```
public class MyWorkout extends BaseActivity{

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
HashMap<String, List<String>> Workouts_details;
List<String> Workout_list;
WorkoutsAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_workout);
    mToolBar = activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Workout");


    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewWorkouts);
    Workouts_details = DataProvider.getInfo();
    Workout_list = new ArrayList<>(Workouts_details.keySet());
    mAdapter = new WorkoutsAdapter(this, Workouts_details, Workout_list);



    expandableListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

As you can see it should be 29,30,31,32,37.. but in reality it is 29,30,32,37,31... Any ideas why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because `HashMap` provides no guarantees about the ordering of its keys in the returned keyset. My guess is that if you subsequently sort the list that you build here, you would get your desired ordering:

```
    Workout_list = new ArrayList<>(Workouts_details.keySet());
    // Now sort Workout_list...
    // As it is simply a list of strings, we can sort it according to its natural ordering (lexicographical) to get your desired result like so:
    java.util.Collections.sort(Workout_list);
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about sorting Workout_list though?

Comment: @LBJ33 I updated the answer to also include sorting of the list according to its natural ordering (lexicographical). Does it work now?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken how i can sort it as per order suppose if i am adding `xyz`, `pqr` and `jkl` so i want to see list in same order as i added

Comment: @VikaSGuttE if you want it to show up in the order as you added it, I don't think you need to sort the list in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can change **HashMap to LinkedHashmap**. Like that

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> WorkoutDetails = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```