# Android ExpandableListView displays items randomly

Tags: java, android

So I've got a mobile app that loads several objects from the file system, then sorts them by ID, then adds them as categories to an ExpandableListView. However, although the items remain sorted correctly in the Object[] array, the ExpandableListView changes the order seemingly randomly. 
In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmhbR.png), the events should be ordered as follows:

An event Event ID:4
Event 4 Event ID:3
Event 3 Event ID:2
Event 2 Event ID:1
Event 1 Event ID:0

The array is sorted correctly, but when added to the ExpandableListView, the order is randomized.

Here is the code for my EventsListViewAdapter:

```
public class EventsAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> Events_Category;
private List<String> Events_List;

public EventsAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, List<String>> Movies_Category, List<String> Movies_List) {
    this.context = context;
    this.Events_Category = Movies_Category;
    this.Events_List = Movies_List;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return Events_List.size();
}
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return Events_Category.get(Events_List.get(groupPosition)).size();
}
@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return Events_List.get(groupPosition);
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int parentPosition, int childPosition) {
    return Events_Category.get(Events_List.get(parentPosition)).get(childPosition);
}
@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String group_title = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(com.cpjd.roblu.R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);
    }
    TextView parent_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(com.cpjd.roblu.R.id.parent_txt);
    parent_textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    if(Text.getAPI() > 21) {
        parent_textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    } else {
        parent_textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2C3539"));
    }
    parent_textview.setText(group_title);
    return convertView;
}
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
    String child_title = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(com.cpjd.roblu.R.layout.child_layout, parentView, false);
    }
    TextView child_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(com.cpjd.roblu.R.id.child_txt);
    child_textview.setText(child_title);

    return convertView;

}
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This problem looks similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859893/expandable-list-view-not-in-right-order.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful post, I was able to fix the issue using `LinkedHashMap`. Just replaced all the `HashMap` with `LinkedHashMap` and it's working perfectly. Thanks!